How to make payouts to individuals' credit cards?
We are developing a SaaS solution.
One of the platform's main aspects is the referral and affiliate programs. We pay a commission to the user who brings clients. For the main activity, we could use Stripe. However, we are looking for a service that will help us make remuneration payments to individuals on their cards (which they will connect to the account).
How does it work? For example, the price for a product is $50$, 50% of which is the platform commission, and 50% we pay to the user. We target the EU and US markets, but our legal entity (and its bank) can be outside the EU (if that's matter).
How can this be organized (automatic payouts to individuals)? We are looking for a third-party service for this (we will not develop it ourselves).
Thanks.

Your use-case is supported by Stripe Connect as a share-revenue model. You can implement it using Destination Charge, and each of your user could be an express Connected Account, and you can send payout to them. However Stripe seems to only support Payout to bank account and debit cards (not credit card).
You should write to Stripe Support for further clarification on countries related regulations.

Thank you. I've read that the payout to debit cards work only in US and Canada, Is that correct?
